# Determine phone number based on time zone?

Tags: phone-number

I have a (potentially international) phone number. It may or may not have a country code prefix. Does anyone know of a database that will help me map phone number => time zone? I would even just like to map phone number => country, since I can probably create country => time zone by scraping existing data on the web. This is a more complicated problem than it looks; for example, how do I know if it's a US-based number -- e.g. is it a USA area code, or an international country calling code?

Any language is fine; I can port it.

Comment: Tagging every language you can think of in order to show up in everyone's searches is just tag spam.

Comment: If it doesn't have a country code, you can't necessarily determine country; for example, some parts of each of Australia, Malaysia and Sweden use phone numbers which have 8 digit numbers, with a one-digit area code prefix (preceeded by the STD prefix `0`). 03-9867-5309 is a valid-looking phone number in Australia and Malaysia, while 08-3634-5789 is a valid-looking phone number in Australia and Sweden.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get current time with a phone number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15410591/get-current-time-with-a-phone-number)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best library I know of for parsing phone numbers in arbitrary formats is [libphonenumber](http://code.google.com/p/libphonenumber/).

You can't map countries to time zones for what should be obvious reasons. Both you and someone in California are in the same country, you're not even in close to the same time zones. Other countries are even wider.

Comment: I want an array output of possible time zones.

Answer (score 0):

No. Your primary problem here lwill be that lots of countries share each timezone. Eg UK and Ireland, France, Germany, ITaly etc.

You may be able to guess based on number structure, but your best bet I'm afraid is to try to get the code in any new data.